# Why does my ObservableCollection not update UI on change if it is not initialized at construction?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, observablecollection

I have been at this problem for hours and I cannot figure out why this happens:

I have an `ObservableCollection` inside my view model. With the following code everything works fine:

```
class ExcelViewModel
{
  public ObservableCollection<EPCInformation> EPCEntries { get; set; }

  public ExcelViewModel()
  {
    EPCEntries = new ObservableCollection<EPCInformation>();
  }

  void AddEntry()
  {
    EPCEntries.Add(new EPCInformation
    {
      HexEPC = "TEST"
    });
  }
}
```

But if I do not initialize `EPCEntries` at construction, but simply set it to an `ObservableCollection` created later, my UI does not update:

```
class ExcelViewModel
{
  public ObservableCollection<EPCInformation> EPCEntries { get; set; }

  public ExcelViewModel()
  {
  }

  void AddEntry()
  {
    ObservableCollection<EPCInformation> tmp = new ObservableCollection<EPCInformation>();
    tmp.Add(new EPCInformation
    {
      HexEPC = "TEST"
    });
    EPCEntries = tmp;
  }
}
```

The `AddEntry()` is called on button click in both cases.

I am new to WPF and C#, but I was thinking that in the second case some other type of event is raised and that is why the UI does not update. Although I could not figure it out.

What am I missing?

Comment: When your code sets/changes the `EPCEntries` property **after** the view established the binding(s) to this property, WPF's binding mechanism and the view won't know the value of the `EPCEntries` property has changed because ExcelViewModel doesn't raise a property change notification when the value of `EPCEntries` has been changed. Look into how to properly implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface for your view models...

Comment: Your `ObservableCollection` is observable, but the property `EPCEntries` isn't. When you first bind `EPCEntries` is null, so WPF ignores it. When you later set `EPCEntries` to something, WPF doesn't know it's changed because you aren't raising a `PropertyChanged` event. This doesn't happen in the first case because the constructor runs before WPF tries to bind to your view model.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. So if I inherit from `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise the `PropertyChanged` event when `EPCEntries` changes, the UI will know about the change, correct?

Comment: Yes, if implemented correctly, the binding mechanism will be notified by the view model that the property value has changed, which will cause the binding mechanism to get the new value from the property (the ObservableCollection<T> object instance) and provide it to the respective binding target(s) in your view...

Comment: You should always implement inotifypropertychanged in a viewmodel. There's a risk of memory leak otherwise but you'll otherwise continue to see weird behaviour as well. Create a base class. My advice would be not to put an equality check in your setter. When you just happen to set a property to the same value, the setter will raise notifypropertychanged but so what? This is rarely of any significance. Should you do that if test then remember a complex type may test as equal and your notification mysteriously fails.

Comment: Default equality of complex types is on type if you can't rely on reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you can change your class around to get INotifyPropertyChanged implemented to update the UI properly.

```
public class ExcelViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   //add private member and use RaisePropertyChanged in setter. 
   private ObservableCollection<EPCInformation> _epcEntries;
   public ObservableCollection<EPCInformation> EPCEntries 
   { 
         get {return _epcEntries;} 
         set
         {
            if (value == _epcEntries) return;
            _epcEntries = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
         }
   }

   public ExcelViewModel()
   {
     EPCEntries = new ObservableCollection<EPCInformation>();
   }

   void AddEntry()
   {
      EPCEntries.Add(new EPCInformation{HexEPC = "TEST"});
   }

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
   {
       PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }
}
```