# Drawing a collection of custom objects in a Canvas

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

In my WPF Application, I have a canvas bound to an ObservableCollection of a custom object, but I can't manage to draw them. I have followed various questions answers on SO but still missing something.

My XAML :

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Trees}">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:Tree}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Species}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.Resources>
            
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas IsItemsHost="True"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=PosX}" />
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=PosY}" />
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

</ListBox>
```

**Edit** : I removed most of the code because it wasn't easy to understand and not relevant to my problem. The following code is enough to understand the problem.

Basically, when I added a new Tree in my collection, it wasn't drawn. There was no problem adding it, but my canvas didn't display my coollection.

ViewModel.cs

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Tree> Trees { get; set; }

    public ViewModel() { }

    public void OnCreateTreeCommand()
    {
        Trees = new ObservableCollection<Tree>();
        Trees.Add(new Tree("Birch", 50, 50));
    }
}
```

Tree.cs

```
public class Tree
{
    public string Species { get; set; }
    public int PosX { get; set; }
    public int PosY { get; set; }

    public Tree (string species, int posX, int posY)
    {
        Species = species;
        PosX = posX;
        PosY = posY;
    }
}
```

There are other steps in between (Trees is not in the VM), but the code implemented INotifyPropertyChanged so no problems there.

The mistake was just :

```
public class StackOverflowVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Tree> _trees;
    public ObservableCollection<Tree> Trees
    {
        get => _trees;
        set
        {
            if (value == _trees) return;
            _trees = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

As the `ObservableCollection` wasn't instanciated in the constructor, I still needed INotifyPropertyChanged. Once done, everything is working properly.

Big thanks to @Mike Nakis for his answer and making me rewrite my minimal example : turns out sometimes it doesn't *just* help other people understand what you want to do.
Indeed, when writing it, I put `Trees = new ObservableCollection<Tree>();` in the constructor and everything worked, which helped me figure out where did the problem came from.

Updated question is most likely a duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/a/56687798/18486478

Comment: You will definitely need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and you will definitely need to invoke `OnPropertyChanged()` from within your setters.  For any further insights, you will need to post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and when I say minimal, I really mean minimal: use just one canvas, one drawable entity, no unnecessary complications.

Comment: So I managed to make it work with my minimal example. I should really focus on doing that carefully rather than trying to explain my problem bacause I can find a solution or explain it easily. Still not understanding why it doesn't work, but I'm on good tracks. I'll edit the post with more details if I can't find a solution.